# Java wait() does not get waked by notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Hallo I've been debugging my code for a whole day already, but I just can't see where could be wrong.

I use SerialPortEventListener on a main thread, in a working thread I have a client socket communicating to a server.
Since after this working thread reach `return`, I still need some wrap up work done in the main thread, i want to create a "pseudothread" that wait in the main thread until the it is notified from the listener onEvent method.

but this pseudothread seems to be waiting forever.

I checked the locked thread `pseudoThread`, they should have the same object id in the Runnable and in Listener class.

"PseudoThread waiting" got displayed, but PseudoThread awake is never showed.

> Console output shows: 
>   PseudoThread waiting 
>   ..
>   ..
>   false notified pseudothread.

**PS if I create a lock in Main class with `public final Object lock = new Object();` and replace all `main.pseudoThread` with `main.lock`, I get java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException.**

```
private class Pseudo implements Runnable{
    Main main;
    public Pseudo(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(main.pseudoThread){
            try {
                System.out.println("PseudoThread waiting");
                main.pseudoThread.wait();
                System.out.println("PseudoThread awake");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.initArduino();
    //more code. including starting the working thread
    main.pseudoThread = new Thread(main.new Pseudo(main));
        main.pseudoThread.start();
        try {
            main.pseudoThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
private void initArduino() {
    arduino = new Arduino(this);
    if(!arduino.initialize())
        System.exit(1);
}
```

and in the listener class (which also runs in main thread)

```
//class constructor;
public Arduino(Main Main){
    this.main = Main;
}
//listening method
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent){
    //some code to interract with working thread.
    record();

}
private void record(){
        synchronized(main.pseudoThread){
            main.pseudoThread.notify();
            System.out.println("notified pseudothread.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling interrupt() instead of notify();

Comment: sorry now corrected. I was trying to get around the problem with interrupt..

Comment: side note : It is bad to *synchronize* on the *thread instance* itself.. --> `synchronized(main.pseudoThread)`

Comment: Does this code compile fine? you can not use this in static context.
arduino = new Arduino(this);

Comment: sorry i modified my original code to make it compacter, but seems i got it wrong. yes it compiled fine.

Comment: @TheLostMind Coult you clearify why it is bad? It is the same POJO as any other object in Java, so i disagree.

Comment: It is very, very important to compile and test the exact code you are going to post, to make sure it reproduces your problem.

Comment: i think this is what @TheLostMind is talking about : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29  it says, " It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by james it could be lost notification case or it could be that..  Two Threads 1- Your Main Thread and  2-  Pseudo  thread Are waiting on  the same Thread Instance Lock (main.pseudoThread)( **Main thread waits on the same lock by calling join method**). 
Now you are using notify which wakes the Main thread from join method and not the one 
waiting in your Pseudo. To check for the second case try calling notifyall in record this will either
confirm the second case or will rule this possibility.

Anyways please refactor your code not to use synch on Thread instance its bad practice. Go for ReentrantLock or CoundDownLatch something.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the notifyall

Comment: You are right! I missed the point that `join` is also waiting, after changing to notifyall, the pseudoThread can be awaken now. Could you also explain why it's a bad habit to synchron on thread instance? @TheLostMind mentioned it before, but didn't elaborate

Comment: 1.In Order for join to works, whenever a thread dies (i.e completes it run method ) it does a notifyAll. So if you are doing synch on thread instance then you will be getting notification even when you don't expect any notification. Try running this code -> http://pastebin.com/SWytLLZQ you will understand

Comment: 2.Either Use new Lock interfaces to handle Concurrency for better design  or "final Objects obj = new Object() " as your locking mechanism (this approach may not be feasible in some scenarios). Its better to  use ReentrantLock, CountDownLatch and Concurrent Data Structures   for concurrency

Answer (score 2):

Without looking too deeply into what might actually be happening, I can see that your use of wait()/notify() is all wrong.  Probably you are experiencing a "lost notification."  The notify() function does *nothing* if there is no thread waiting for it at the moment when it is called.  If your serialEvent() function calls notify() before the other thread calls wait(), then the notification will be lost.

Consider this example:

```
class WaitNotify() {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private long head = 0;
    private long tail = 0;

    public void consumer() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while(head == tail) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            doSomething();
            count head += 1;
        }
    }

    public void producer() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            tail += 1;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

The essential points are:

(1) The consumer() function waits for some relationship between data to become true:  Here, it waits for `head != tail`.

(2) The consumer() function waits in a loop.  There's two reasons for that:  (a) Many programs have more than one consumer thread.  If consumer A wakes up from the wait(), there's no guarantee that consumer B hasn't already claimed whatever it was that they both were waiting for.  And (b) The Java language spec allows foo.wait() to sometimes return even when foo.notify() has not been called.  That's known as a "spurious wakeup."  Allowing spurious wakeups (so long as they don't happen too often) makes it easier to implement a JVM.

(3) The lock object is the *same* lock that is used by the program to protect the variables upon which the condition depends.  If this example was part of a larger program, you would see `synchronized(lock)` surrounding every use of head and tail regardless of whether the synchronized code is wait()ing or notify()ing.

If your own code obeys all three of the above rules when calling wait() and notify(), then your program will be far more likely to behave the way you expect it to behave.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. But I goal to use `wait()` and `notify()` is not to synchronize over any critical object but simply keep the whole program running until notified.

Comment: Also I don't understand why if I lock an object declared in Main class as field, the compiler gives IllegalMonitorStateException. Maybe it gives a hint to my error?

Comment: @yfi, IllegalMonitorStateException means you called foo.wait() or foo.notify() from a thread that did _not_ have foo locked.  As far as I know, the Java library doesn't throw that exception for any other reeason.

Comment: @yfi, You're missing my point.  It doesn't matter whether there is a 'critical object' or not, but if you want to wait(), you must wait _in a loop_ for some object to change state; and if you want to notify a waiting thread, you must change the state of that same object before you call notify().  The "state" can be as simple as a boolean flag, but it has to be something you can test in your while loop.  That's how wait() and notify() were designed to be used.

Comment: do I have to use while or it is the common usage of wait() and notify()? here I just want to block the pseudoThread in order to keep the whole program running (I assume otherwise, the program would just finish after the working thread ends).
As for the IllegalMonitorException, I think it's very strange, since I do have `synchronized(lock)`, where lock is the same object, in both thread

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `notify` and `wait` seem to be incorrect. Method name notify can be a bit misleading because it is not for general purpose "notifying". These methods are used to control the execution of synchronization blocks. Wait will allow some other thread to synchronize with same object while current threads pauses. Basically this is used when some resource is not available and execution can not continue. On the other hand notify will wake one waiting thread wake from wait after notifying thread has completed its synchronized-block. Only one thread can be in synchronized block of the same object at the same time.

If the idea is just keep the main program running until notified then semaphore would be much more appropriate. Something like this.

```
public void run() {
   System.out.println("PseudoThread waiting");
   main.semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly();
   System.out.println("PseudoThread awake");
}
//...
private void record(){
   main.semaphore.release();
}
//...
public static void main(String[] args) {
   main.semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
   //...
}
```

Comment: But I read notify and wait are just binare Semaphor, so I don't understand where the advantage is. Another note: my main thread is a listener, wouldn't `aquireUninterruptibly` (even aquire itself) block by listener method?
And at this point I noticed in my own code `join()` seems to block the listener thread as well..

Comment: Notify and wait are not semaphores they are quite essential part of mutual exclusion (mutex) block implementation. It is used to ensure that only one process is executed protected code. Notify and wait are used to avoid polling some condition instead they allow given process go to sleep and wake them up.

Mutex, notify and wait can be used to implement semaphore.

Comment: Main thread blocks already when you are using wait. The whole idea of listening (in this context) is wait something to happen. Semaphore does just that.

record(..) method will raise semaphore / release so listening thread can woke up.

Comment: The advantage (in this situation) compared to mutex is that semaphore fits for the job better. It is less error prone and easier to made work the way wanted. In some other cases things can be different.