# wait and notify with implementing Runnable and extending Thread example

Tags: java, multithreading

I am implementing the logic to understand wait and notify works i found something which i am not able to analyze when i am extending the class with thread then wait and notify is working as expected but when i am implementing the runnable interface then output will be differ

```
public class AdderThread extends Thread {

int total;

@Override
public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            total += i;
        }

        notify();
    }

}





public class WaitNotify {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AdderThread addrTh = new AdderThread();
    addrTh.start();
    // -1243309312

    System.out.println("Total without Wait() " + addrTh.total);


}
```

}

When Implementing Runnable gives me correct answer means it is waitng for the thread to complete the task but when i am using extends thread it is giving me answer as 0 i.e. it is not waiting for thread to complete the task.

```
public class WaitNotify {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AdderThread addrTh = new AdderThread();
    addrTh.start();
    // -1243309312

    System.out.println("Total Before Wait " + addrTh.total);
    synchronized (addrTh) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Sum...");
            addrTh.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Total " + addrTh.total);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: At the start you wrote extends is working, runnable not. At the end you're saying runnable works, extends not. Did you read what you typed?

Comment: Sorry ... i mean to say that when i am extending thread then without wait()  my result is not comming correctly because thread is still running.But, when i am implementing Runnable my result is comming correctly without using wait()

Answer (score 1):

Your new thread can call `notify()` before the main thread calls `wait()."  The wait() call will wait forever in that case because notify() does not do anything at all if some other thread is not already waiting for it.

`wait()` and `notify()` are low-level operations that are meant to be used in a very specific way:

See [Java wait() does not get waked by notify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655143/java-wait-does-not-get-waked-by-notify/24661778#24661778) for more information.

---

The difference between the case where you implement `Runnable` and the case where you extend `Thread` is due to the fact that `this` refers to an anonymous inner class in the first case, and it refers to the `Thread` object in the latter case.

That matters because the thread machinery uses wait() and notify() for its own purposes.  So if your `wait()` call comes too late to be waked up by the `notify()` call in your code, it may still get waked up by a `notify()` in library code (e.g., when the thread terminates).  That won't happen when you implement `Runnable` because there's no reason why the library would ever notify it.

Comment: you mean to say that in case of runnable even if we do not call the wait() it will be called automatically. Can you give me details in brief thanks.

Comment: No.  I am saying that the `Thread` class uses `wait()` and `notify()`.  If your application defines a subclass of Thread with a custom `run()` method, and your run() method calls `this.wait()`, that can waked up by a notify() call in the library.  If your application defines an anonymous inner class with a run() method that calls this.wait(), that can _only_ be waked up by your own code.