# Need explanation for Lost Notification occuring in a JavaPathFinder example

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am trying but unable to understand how the following program creates a liveness error (Thanks james large!). I understand what happens, because I have used Java Path Finder and its trace tells me that notifyAll() is called, and then two threads call wait. This means that those threads wait indefinitely, hence the deadlock. That is what I understood so far, but I cannot grasp the process that each thread executes in order for this to happen, and would appreciate some help getting there. The code is as follows:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014, United States Government, as represented by the
 * Administrator of the National Aeronautics and Space Administration.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * The Java Pathfinder core (jpf-core) platform is licensed under the
 * Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. 
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * This example shows a deadlock that occurs as a result of a missed signal,
 * i.e. a wait() that happens after the corresponding notify().
 * 
 * The defect is caused by a violated monitor encapsulation, i.e. directly
 * accessing monitor internal data ('Event.count') from concurrent clients
 * ('FirstTask', 'SecondTask'), without synchronization with the
 * corresponding monitor operations ('wait_for-Event()' and 'signalEvent()').
 * 
 * The resulting race is typical for unsafe optimizations that try to 
 * avoid expensive blocking calls by means of local caches
 * 
 * This example was inspired by a defect found in the "Remote Agent" 
 * spacecraft controller that flew on board of "Deep Space 1", as described
 * in: 
 * 
 *   Model Checking Programs
 *   W. Visser, K. Havelund, G. Brat, S. Park and F. Lerda
 *   Automated Software Engineering Journal
 *   Volume 10, Number 2, April 2003
 *  
 * @author wvisser
 */

//------- the test driver
public class oldclassic {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Event      new_event1 = new Event();
    Event      new_event2 = new Event();

FirstTask  task1 = new FirstTask(new_event1, new_event2);
SecondTask task2 = new SecondTask(new_event1, new_event2);

task1.start();
task2.start();
  }
}

//------- shared objects implemented as monitors
class Event {
  int count = 0;

  public synchronized void signal_event () {

    // NOTE: this abstraction is not strictly required - even if the state space would
    // be unbound, JPF could still find the error at a reasonable search depth,
    // unless it's left-most branch in the search tree is unbound. If it is,
    // there are two ways to work around: (1) use a different search strategy
    // (e.g. HeuristicSearch with BFSHeuristic), or (2) set a random choice
    // enumeration order ("+cg.randomize_choices=true"). In this example, (2)
    // works just fine
    count = (count + 1) % 3;
    //count++;  // requires "+cg.randomize_choices=true" for DFSearch policy

    notifyAll();
  }

  public synchronized void wait_for_event () {
    try {
      wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}

//------- the two concurrent threads using the monitors
class FirstTask extends Thread {
  Event event1;
  Event event2;
  int   count = 0;  // bad optimization - local cache of event1 internals

  public FirstTask (Event e1, Event e2) {
    this.event1 = e1;
    this.event2 = e2;
  }

  @Override
  public void run () {
    count = event1.count;          // <race> violates event1 monitor encapsulation

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("1");

      if (count == event1.count) { // <race> ditto
        event1.wait_for_event();
      }

      count = event1.count;        // <race> ditto
      event2.signal_event();       // updates event2.count
    }
  }
}

class SecondTask extends Thread {
  Event event1;
  Event event2;
  int   count = 0;  // bad optimization - local cache of event2 internals

  public SecondTask (Event e1, Event e2) {
    this.event1 = e1;
    this.event2 = e2;
  }

  @Override
  public void run () {
    count = event2.count;          // <race> violates event2 monitor encapsulation

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("  2");
      event1.signal_event();       // updates event1.count

      if (count == event2.count) { // <race> ditto
        event2.wait_for_event();
      }

      count = event2.count;        // <race> ditto
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: Your problem is not called "deadlock", it's called "lost notification".  Deadlock means that thread A has _locked_ resource 1 and it can not proceed until thread B unlocks resource 2, while at the same time, thread B has locked resource 2, and can not proceed until thread A unlocks resource 1.  Lost notification is when thread A calls `o.notify()` before thread B calls `o.wait()`, and then thread B ends up waiting forever.  The generic name that covers all kinds of problem is "liveness error."

Comment: I described it as a Deadlock since that is what the Java Path Finder writes on its output. But I understood what you said.
Can you confirm that it is a lost notification (i.e. can you explain me how that happens in this particular instance)?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to an earlier question that was similar to yours:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655143/java-wait-does-not-get-waked-by-notify/24661778#24661778

Comment: I read and understood your answer to the other question. You mention some key points, but I still don't comprehend just how in this particular example `notify()` can be called before `wait()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless ways in which the operations performed by the two threads could be interleaved.  Some of them will lead to lost notifications.  Here's one very simple example:

1. Task2 enters its `run()` method, prints "  2", calls
   `event1.signal_event()`, and then blocks in
   `event2.wait_for_event()`.
2. Then task1 enters its `run()` method, prints "1", and blocks in `event1.wait_for_event()`.

At this point, both threads are blocked, waiting for notifications that will never happen.

This is a very simple serialization, but it is a *possible* serialization, and there are many others that will lead to the same situation.

Comment: I tested and tested and tested, allways presuming Task1 would take the first step. Assuming Task2 runs first just makes the error stand in plain sight. I was struggling over this example for longer than I'd care to admit...
I cannot thank you enough, james!