# why is notify not getting called in my java code

Tags: java, multithreading, inter-process-communicat

Here's my code:

```
public class ProducerConsumer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ProduceCosumeData p = new ProduceCosumeData();
        ProducerT pt= new ProducerT(p); // with p obj i am creating thread
        ConsumerT ct=new ConsumerT(p); // with same p obj i am creating thread
        pt.start();
        ct.start();  //i am starting 2 threads
    }
}

class ProduceCosumeData
{
    boolean flag;
    public synchronized void printStringP(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            try{
                if(flag)   //for frist time flag is flase so, wait will skip
                    wait();
                else
                    flag=true;    //for next time onwards wait() will get call

                System.out.print("Pay");
                notify();//after this why my wait() not canceling in inprintStringC()
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void printStringC(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            try{
                wait();   // why it is not out of this after notify()
                System.out.print("Tm");
                notify();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ProducerT extends Thread
{
    ProduceCosumeData p;
    ProducerT(ProduceCosumeData p)
    { 
        this.p=p;   // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }   
    public void run()
    {
        p.printStringP(10); //it will print 10 times pay
    }
}

class ConsumerT extends Thread
{
    ProduceCosumeData p;
    ConsumerT(ProduceCosumeData p)
    { 
        this.p=p;   // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }
    public void run()
    {
        p.printStringC(10);   //it will print 10 times tm
    }
}
```

I am expecting the following output:

> PayTm
>   PayTm
>   PayTm
>   ... 10 times

but what I'm getting output is this:

> Pay..

This is followed by a long wait.

The above two functions are in same object.
Why is the notify not releasing the wait() function? Even when I use notifyAll(), the output remains the same.

Comment: `printStringP` might call `notify` while `printStringC` is still waiting to enter the method (since it's synchronized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code, one of your threads is calling notify and the other is still not waiting. This produces a deadlock with both threads waiting.

You need to fix your use of the synchronization flag, don't call wait if it is not needed. Also, checking the locking condition is still available after the wait() is a good practice.

This is your `ProduceConsumeData` class with the use of the flag fixed:

```
class ProduceCosumeData
{
    boolean flag;
    public synchronized void printStringP(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            try{
                while (flag == true) {   
                    wait();
                }
                flag=true;
                System.out.print("Pay");
                notify();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public synchronized void printStringC(int n)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            try{
                while(flag == false) {
                    wait();
                }
                System.out.print("Tm");
                flag = false;
                notify();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine . thank you.
Now i have learn 2 concepts
1) Dealock code
2)How to slove deadlock
One more question
why you have used 
       while (flag == true) {   
                     wait();
                  }
we can also use
        if(flag == true) {   
                    wait();
                }
is there any problem using if .

Comment: @Yugandhar You can use the `if` instead of the `while` but it is a good practice to check the condition again after the `wait()`. For example, if the class is modified to add more functionality and the lock of the class is used somewhere else, your synchronization would be broken. The code is more robust if you check the condition again after `wait()`

Comment: @Yugandhar _Deadlock_  means two or more threads, and each of them is waiting for one of the others to do something.  But the problem that got you into the deadlock is called _lost notification_, and that's what you have to learn to avoid in this case.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655143/java-wait-does-not-get-waked-by-notify/24661778#24661778

Answer (score -1):

In the second iteration of `printStringP` the attribute `flag` is `true` and then the two threads are waiting.

Comment: You *need to* hold the lock to call `wait`.

Answer (score -1):

You have used a general `wait()` with the synchronization in the method. Try using an object-synchronised version, such as `synchronized(this){ wait(); }` then whatever, to prevent cyclic dependencies of multiple threads on the same object, which is very very dangerous for any multithreaded program.

Or, more simply, implement a proper `clone()` method in your `ProducerConsumerData` class, and then to the 1st thread pass this object, and to the next pass its clone. Try using `p.clone()` instead of `p` in the second thread's constructor.

As answered above, you can make printStringP() 's notify() only get called when flag is true, not always.

Comment: As my knowledge
no diff b/w synchronized method or block  in this context

Answer (score -1):

This is the classic misconception that trips up almost everyone who tries to use `wait` and `notify`. Really they are so old and broken they shouldn't even be taught any more IMHO.

When `printStringP` calls `notify()` `printStringC` **is not waiting** yet.

```
class ProduceCosumeData {
    // Variable shared between threads should be volatile.
    volatile boolean flag;

    public synchronized void printStringP(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                //for frist time flag is flase so, wait will skip
                if (flag) {
                    System.err.println("Waiting in printStringP");
                    wait();
                } else {
                    System.err.println("flag now true");
                    flag = true;    //for next time onwards wait() will get call
                }
                System.out.print("Pay");
                System.err.println("printStringP notify");
                notify();//after this why my wait() not canceling in inprintStringC()
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void printStringC(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                System.err.println("Waiting in printStringC");
                wait();   // why it is not out of this after notify()
                System.out.print("Tm");
                System.err.println("printStringC notify");
                notify();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ProducerT extends Thread {

    ProduceCosumeData p;

    ProducerT(ProduceCosumeData p) {
        this.p = p;   // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }

    public void run() {
        p.printStringP(10); //it will print 10 times pay
    }
}

class ConsumerT extends Thread {

    ProduceCosumeData p;

    ConsumerT(ProduceCosumeData p) {
        this.p = p;   // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }

    public void run() {
        p.printStringC(10);   //it will print 10 times tm
    }
}

public void test() {
    ProduceCosumeData p = new ProduceCosumeData();
    ProducerT pt = new ProducerT(p); // with p obj i am creating thread
    ConsumerT ct = new ConsumerT(p); // with same p obj i am creating thread
    pt.start();
    ct.start();  //i am starting 2 threads
}
```

prints

```
flag now true
PayprintStringP notify
Waiting in printStringP
Waiting in printStringC
```

To fix this **don't use wait/notify** it is broken for all but the very experienced. The same functionality can be achieved in a stable fashion using `Lock`s and `Condition`s or almost any other `java.util.concurrent` class.

Answer (score -2):

```
Please find the below code snippet.

package com.java.examples;

public class ProducerConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProduceCosumeData p = new ProduceCosumeData();
        ProducerT pt = new ProducerT(p); // with p obj i am creating thread
        ConsumerT ct = new ConsumerT(p); // with same p obj i am creating thread
        pt.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ct.start(); // i am starting 2 threads
    }
}

class ProduceCosumeData {
    boolean flag = false;

    public synchronized void printStringP(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                if (flag) {
                    notify();
                } else
                    flag = true;
                System.out.println("Pay");
                if (i <= n - 1) {
                    wait();
                } else {
                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void printStringC(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                if (flag) {
                    System.out.println("Tm");
                    if (i <= n - 1) {
                        notify();
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else
                    flag = false;
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class ProducerT extends Thread {
    ProduceCosumeData p;

    ProducerT(ProduceCosumeData p) {
        this.p = p; // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }

    public void run() {
        p.printStringP(10); // it will print 10 times pay
    }
}

class ConsumerT extends Thread {
    ProduceCosumeData p;

    ConsumerT(ProduceCosumeData p) {
        this.p = p; // i am saving the same obj for both threads
    }

    public void run() {
        p.printStringC(10); // it will print 10 times tm
    }
}
```