# common data in two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have two threads. One will increment my variable and the other one will show it on the screen just after it is incremented.

I want to use the `wait()` and `notifyAll()` functions to do that but I have some problems.

I have written this code, but it stops working at some point (it shows only the first and the last number: 1 and 10).

```
public class TestClass {
    static int x = 0;
    public static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.wait();
                            System.out.println(x);
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void  run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        x++;
                        lock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding additional `notifyAll()` in the first thread and `wait()` in the second one(`t2`) but it still doesn't work. How can I do that right?

Comment: As long as your reading thread is only reading the `x` variable, you don't need to lock it's action. Further, it could simply wake up periodically and report the value: there is no need for it to be notified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655143/java-wait-does-not-get-waked-by-notify/24661778#24661778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working solution. Key is in adding an additional flag that will indicate whether the writing thread has the right to write. Note `final` on the lock object, that is a good practice.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static int x = 0;
    private static final Object lock = new Object();  
    private static boolean canWrite = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {  
                        synchronized(lock)
                        {                            
                            if(!canWrite)                            
                                lock.wait();
                            System.out.println(x);
                            canWrite = false;
                            lock.notify();
                        }
                    }                    
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        });        

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {                                                
                        synchronized(lock)
                        {                                                              
                            x++;
                            canWrite = true;
                            lock.notify();
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                    }                            
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}                                                                        
            }
        });
        t1.start();        
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()):

> The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object. The awakened threads will
>   compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be
>   actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the
>   awakened threads enjoy no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being
>   the next thread to lock this object.

The thread that you just woke up is not guaranteed to acquire the lock immediately, thus you could have the loop that calls notifyAll() run all its iterations before the other gets woken up.

If you want them to alternate, one way is to have each one take turns waiting

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is confusing but if you want to try to control threads, I suppose it's a useful exercise.

Change your code to give your thread a good name e.g. "test1" and "test2", say.  Run your program and dig out the process ID for it and run

```
jstack <pid>
```

(you can find it in the bin directory of the JDK).  This is (perhaps) what you will see:
**test1** will be waiting one the

```
lock.wait();
```

while **test2** will waiting on

```
lock.wait();
```

as well.

Start at the first iteration.  **test2** wins and calls notify, which has no effect at all because nothing is waiting on the lock.  **test2** then starts waiting.
Now **test1** can enter and immediately goes into a wait.

If **test1** wins the first time, you can get into a cycle that appears to work.

That is why you get the first number (**test2** wins first) or the last number (**test1** wins).

That's pretty much what it looks like to me, but your **jstack** will tell you for sure.
PS: Use CountDownLatch and the concurrency package in general.