# notify and notifyall showing weird behavior to wait of multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, notify

I thought i understand completely what is the difference between notifyAll() and notify() ,But then i suddenly came across this code whose output i cannot able to figure out. So i need some help to understand the weird output...

Note:- After commenting //3 and uncommenting //4 Output is:-

```
Waiting for Calculations...
Waiting for Calculations...
Waiting for Calculations...
Total is : 4950
```

(this seems reasonable as if Thread() starts after 3 waiting threads and as  it calls notifyAll() and one out of waiting thread will get the lock and executes so show the total while other still waits)

and after commenting //4 and uncommenting //3 Output is:-

```
Waiting for Calculations...
Waiting for Calculations...
Waiting for Calculations...
Total is : 4950
Total is : 4950
```

(this is weird i think with reference to first output when Thread() starts after two waiting threads one will get lock and only one should show the total. But Why THE 2ND TOTAL IS SHOWN AS OUTPUT.)

> Code :-

```
class Reader extends Thread {
    Calculator c;

    public Reader(Calculator cal) {
        c = cal;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (c) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for calculations...");
                c.wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            System.out.println("Total is : " + c.total);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arsg[]) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

        //Thread at 3rd and 4th position

        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        new Thread(calculator).start();  //3
        new Reader(calculator).start();
        //new Thread(calculator).start();    //4
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------


class Calculator implements Runnable {

    int total;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                total += i;
            }

            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

> Code is modified and taken from kathy sierra
>   Is it the case of spontaneous Wakeup (other wake up is by jvm)

Comment: It looks as if you expect the reader threads to hit the `c.wait()` call before the calculator thread calls `notifyAll()`, but there's nothing in your code that _guarantees_ that they will run in that order.  The `System.out.println()` call in the readers could give the calculator thread plenty of time to get ahead of the readers.  When your code `wait()`s for a one-time-only notification that already has happened, it will wait forever.  That's called the _lost notification problem_.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655143/java-wait-does-not-get-waked-by-notify/24661778#24661778

Comment: @jameslarge Not the SOP itself, it's within the lock. Just `start` being async.

Comment: Oops!  I wasn't paying enough attention to those synchronized blocks.  But even so, it looks as if you expect the reader threads to enter their `run()` method before the calculator thread enters its `run()` method.  Even _that_ is not guaranteed.  A call to `t.start()` does not wait for the new thread to actually start running before it returns.  The main thread could terminate before any of the new threads enters its `run()` method, and there's no guarantees about the order in which the new threads will get to run.

Comment: Please read line i wrote before "Code:- " , so that u can better understand my problem

Comment: Two threads got notified and therefore two printed after returning from `wait`.

Comment: OK then in first case three total statements should be printed. ??

Comment: No, only one, because only one thread had called `wait` by the time the `notifyAll` got called. Just add a print statement right before the `notifyAll` and you will see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple race condition. In one case, the `notifyAll` happens after only one thread has called `wait`. In the other case, the `notifyAll` happens after two threads have called `wait`. Under different conditions, none or all other threads could/would have called `wait`.

`notifyAll` doesn't work retroactively. It only wakes up those threads that are already `wait`ing, not those that invoke `wait` later.

Comment: Sorry but please ans after considering that in both cases 2 or 3 threads are waiting..

Comment: And i am asking (specifically) why in second case by notifyall call, two threads come to running state...

Comment: @Ronaldo7 Add a log line before the `notifyAll`. You'll see how many have waited before the notify occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer but still i want to post my final modified code that solved all my doubts regarding the question ....

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11881225/

> Code:-

```
class Reader extends Thread
{
    Calculator c;

public Reader(Calculator cal)
{
    c=cal;

}

public void run()
{
    synchronized(c)
    {
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for calculations...");
            c.wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println("Exception occured");}

        System.out.println("Total is : "+c.total);
    }
}   

public static void main(String arsg[])
{
    Calculator calculator=new Calculator();

    new Reader(calculator).start();     
    new Reader(calculator).start();     
    new Reader(calculator).start();     

    new Thread(calculator).start(); // Change position of this line while experimenting


}
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    class Calculator implements Runnable

{
    int total;

public void run()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            total+=i;
        }
        System.out.println("Before Notify");
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("After Notify");
    }
}
}
```